# Wrote script in OSX, with multiprocessing. Now windows won't play ball

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, pool

The program/script I've made works on OSX and linux. It uses selenium to scrape data from some pages, manipulates the data and saves it. In order to be more efficient, I included the multiprocessing pool and manager. I create a pool, for each item in a list, it calles the scrap class, starts a phantomjs instance and scrapes. Since I'm using multiprocessing.pool, and I want a way to pass data between the threads, I read that multiprocessing.manager was the way forward. If I wrote 
`manager = Manager()
info = manager.dict([])`
it would create a dict that could be accessed by all threads. It all worked perfectly.

My issue is that the client wants to run this on a windows machine (I wrote the entire thing on OSX) I assumed, it would be as simple as installing python, selenium and launching it. I had errors which later lead me to writing `if __name__ == '__main__:` at the top of my main.py file, and indenting everything to be inside. The issue is, when I have `class scrape():` outside of the if statement, it cannot see the global info, since it is declared outside of the scope. If I insert the `class scrape():` inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` then i get an attribute error saying

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'scrape'

And if I go back to declaring manager = manager() and info = manager.dict([]) outside of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` then I get the error in windows about making sure I use `if __name__ == '__main__'` it doesn't seem like I can win with this project at the moment.

Code Layout...

```
Imports...
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Manager

manager = Manager()
info = manager.dict([])
date = str(datetime.date.today())

class do_scrape():
    def __init__():
    def...

def scrape_items():#This contains code which creates a pool and then pool.map(do_scrape, s) s = a list of items

def save_scrape():

def update_price():

def main():

main()
```

Basically, the scrape_items is called by main, then scrape_items uses pool.map(do_scrape, s) so it calls the do_scrape class and passes the list of items to it one by one. The do_scrape then scrapes a web page based on the item url in "s" then saves that info in the global info which is the multiprocessing.manager dict. The above code does not show any `if __name__ == '__main__':` statements, it is an outline of how it works on my OSX setup. It runs and completes the task as is. If someone could issue a few pointers, I would appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: add some framework of your code showing position of class manager,class scrape,global variables and line where you are using :if __name__ == '__main__

Comment: You should revisit your reasoning for adding `if __name__ == '__main__:`. I can't see a reason this would only be needed on Windows, and most likely there's a better way.

Comment: @MartinKonecny When I ran the above code on a windows machine, the error I was getting was "Attempt to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase. This probably means that you are on Windows and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module: if __name__ == '__main__':
free_support()
...

Comment: @MartinKonecny THe `if __name__` guard is absolutely required on Windows in places it's not on other platforms. It explains it in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to see your code, but its sounds like you just need to explicitly pass your shared dict to `scrape`, like this:

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial

def scrape(info, item):
   # Use info in here

if __name__ == "__main__":
   manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
   info = manager.dict()
   pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
   func = partial(scrape, info) # use a partial to make it easy to pass the dict to pool.map
   items = [1,2,3,4,5] # This would be your actual data
   results = pool.map(func, items)
   #pool.apply_async(scrape, [shared_dict, "abc"]) # In case you're not using map...
```

Note that you shouldn't put *all* your code inside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard, just the code that's actually creating processes via `multiprocessing`, this includes creating the `Manager` and the `Pool`.

Any method you want to run in a child process must be declared at the top level of the module, because it has to be importable from `__main__` in the child process. When you declared `scrape` inside the `if __name__ ...` guard, it could no longer be imported from the `__main__` module, so you saw the `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'scrape'` error.

**Edit:**

Taking your example:

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial

date = str(datetime.date.today())

#class do_scrape():
#    def __init__():
#    def...
def do_scrape(info, s):
    # do stuff
    # Also note that do_scrape should probably be a function, not a class

def scrape_items():
    # scrape_items is called by main(), which is protected by a`if __name__ ...` guard 
    # so this is ok.
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    info = manager.dict([])
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    func = partial(do_scrape, info) 
    s = [1,2,3,4,5] # Substitute with the real s
    results = pool.map(func, s)     

def save_scrape():

def update_price():

def main():
    scrape_items()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # Note that you can declare manager and info here, instead of in scrape_items, if you wanted
    #manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    #info = manager.dict([])
    main()
```

One other important note here is that the first argument to `map` should be a function, not a class. This is stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) (`multiprocessing.map` is meant to be equivalent to the built-in map).

Comment: Thanks for this, I am however new to python and don't fully understand the solution. I tried the partial function from functools, but no joy.

Comment: @user3387507 Can you be more specific about what "no joy" means?

Comment: I can't since I don't fully understand the solution. I'm clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: @user3387507 I updated my answer to look more like your example code. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Thanks for the edited code. "do_scrape" should be scrape, i changed it because i read that it might be a solution if I'd ever har a file called scrape.py in the directory. the scrape class has different functions for scraping different things etc... Thats why its a class. This solution seems the closest, however I get a pickling error now. "multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result '.scrape instance' Reason UnpickleableError

Comment: I think you're getting that because you're trying to call `map` on a class instead of a function. The class apparently isn't pickleable in its current form. When you call `map` on the class, an instance of the class gets returned, which `map` will try to return to the parent process by pickling it. Since the class isn't pickleable, you get the error you see. You should really be calling `map` on a function, even if all that function does is instantiate an instance of `scrape`.

Comment: Thanks so much! The solution above worked perfectly, after I created a new function do_scrape() which instantiated an instance of scrape(). Works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Find the starting point of your program, and make sure you wrap only that with your `if` statement. For example:

```
Imports...
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Manager

manager = Manager()
info = manager.dict([])
date = str(datetime.date.today())

class do_scrape():
    def __init__():
    def...

def scrape_items():#This contains code which creates a pool and then pool.map(do_scrape, s) s = a list of items

def save_scrape():

def update_price():

def main():

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Essentially the contents of the `if` are only executed if you called this file directly when running your python code. If this file/module is included as an import from another file, all attributes will be defined, so you can access various attributes without actually beginning execution of the module.

Read more here:
[What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: I tried this solution and I still get the same error about needing if __name__ == '__main__':

Comment: Make sure you wrap the code that starts your multi process with the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block

Comment: Just to clarify - if you wrap your entire code block with `if name == main`, then the file is essentially empty/useless if imported from another module (the `if` statement will evaluate to false). If you place your `if` statement simply to prevent automatic execution, all the attributes/functions will be visible, and you will avoid the problem where execution of your module begins before you want it to.